# Cobertura - Code Coverage Instrumentation

Tags: ant, build, cobertura

I am trying some code-coverage analysis for first time and I was working on getting cobertura using ANT. My questions might be silly, but thought of asking here. I have the following in my ANT scripts. While reading over through cobertura the next step was instrumentation. What is code coverage instrumentation?

```
<target name="cobertura" depends="checkstyle">
    <property name="cobertura.dir" location="C:\\Softwares- packages\\Corbetura\\cobertura-1.9.4.1" />
    <path id ="cobertura.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${cobertura.dir}">
        <include name="cobertura.jar"/>
        <include name="lib/**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    </path>     
    <taskdef resource="tasks.properties" classpathref="cobertura.classpath"/>

</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

cobertura modifies your class files so that it can compute the coverage. I typically 'instrument' a copy of the jar files that I use for executing tests and use a copy that hasn't been instrument as my build artifact.

Here is the build file I used when I first set up cobertura via ant:

The cobertura-instrument target instruments my code and writes the instrumented classes to a separate directory like you said.

The junit target compiles the test, then instruments the tests, then runs the tests, then produces the report. These steps are all done by declaring dependent targets to the junit one.

```
<path id="cobertura.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${cobertura.dir}">
    <include name="cobertura.jar" />
    <include name="lib/**/*.jar" />
  </fileset>
</path>

<taskdef classpathref="cobertura.classpath" resource="tasks.properties" />
```

```
<!-- Delete an existing coburtura datafile -->
<delete file="${cobertura.datafile}"/>
<antcall target="cobertura.clean"/>

<!-- Instrument the code with cobertura to test for coverage -->
<cobertura-instrument todir="${cobertura.instrumented.classes}" datafile="${cobertura.datafile}">
   <fileset dir="${build.dir}/classes/">
       <include name="**/*.class"/>
   </fileset>
</cobertura-instrument>
```

```
 <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.java" />
 </fileset>
 <fileset dir="${tests.src.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.java" />
 </fileset>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Eric.Please correct me if I am wrong. Once the build is complete, corebetura will create another copy of the binaries and will perform the unit testing. Depending on this it generates the reporting. So can i tell instrumentation is copying the binaries and perform test execution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the "cobertura-instrument" task. See [here](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html)